# parsley validation pattern doesn't accept empty string

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I'm using parsley patter attribute to validate file names:

```
<input pattern="^\w+\.\w+$"/>
```

but it say it's valid when input text is empty. How can I make empty text invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set required attribute.

```
<input pattern="^\w+\.\w+$" required="true"/>
```